# LotusScript to create a calendar entry in MS outlook

Tags: outlook, calendar, lotusscript

Any help or source to create a calendar entry (appointment) in outlook using lotus script. Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: What did you try to find a solution? Try to find a solution for Visual Basic pr VBA, then just use that as LotusScript works similar enough...

Comment: Send an ICS file or  a regular invitation.